# How can I import an RSA public key from either XML or modulus/exponent in native code for use with Windows CAPI's CryptVerifySignature?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, public-key, cryptoapi, mscapi

In C#, I am able to validate a hash against a public key in either of the following ways:

```
// Import from raw modulus and exponent
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()) {
    RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = new RSAParameters {Modulus = modulus, Exponent = exponent};
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);
    return rsa.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"), signature);
}

// Import from XML
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()) {
    rsa.FromXmlString(xmlPublicKey);
    return rsa.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"), signature);
}
```

What I need to know is how I can use CAPI to accomplish the same thing, given an inbound RSA public key?

I have most of the CAPI functions necessary to validate a hash, except for understanding how to import a public key into the cryptographic provider's context:

```
HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
HCRYPTHASH hHash;

CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0);
CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA512, 0, 0, &hHash);
CryptHashData(hHash, pDataToHash, lenDataToHash, 0);
CryptVerifySignature(hHash, pSignature, sigLength, NULL, CRYPT_NOHASHOID);
CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`CryptImportKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380207.aspx) with a [`PUBLICKEYBLOB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375601.aspx):

```
HCRYPTKEY hPublicKey;
DWORD keyBlobLength = sizeof(BLOBHEADER)+sizeof(RSAPUBKEY)+modulusLengthInBytes;
BYTE* keyBlob = malloc(keyBlobLength);
BLOBHEADER* blobheader = (BLOBHEADER*) keyBlob;
blobheader.bType    = PUBLICKEYBLOB;
blobheader.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
blobheader.reserved = 0;
blobheader.aiKeyAlg = CALG_RSA_KEYX;
RSAPUBKEY* rsapubkey = (RSAPUBKEY*) (keyBlob + sizeof(BLOBHEADER));
rsapubkey.magic     = 0x31415352;
rsapubkey.bitlen    = modulusLengthInBytes*8;
rsapubkey.pubexp    = 65537;         // Or whatever your public exponent is.
BYTE* modulus = keyBlob + sizeof(BLOBHEADER) + sizeof(RSAPUBKEY);
memcpy(modulus, ..., modulusLengthInBytes); // NOTE: modulus must be in LSB form,
                                     //       which is the opposite of what you
                                     //        usually have. 
                                     //       .NET will give you the modulus in
                                     //       MSB form, so you will have to
                                     //       reverse the order of the bytes.
CryptImportKey(hCryptProv, keyBlob, keyBlobLength, 0, 0, &hPublicKey);
```

Comment: The XML format used by .NET is incompatible with *any* of the key BLOB formats used in CAPI. There is an `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportCspBlob()` method which might help the transition from .NET to CAPI.

Comment: MSDN link for PUBLICKEYBLOB is dead.  Try this link instead.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Code correction:
`RSAPUBKEY* rsapubkey = (RSAPUBKEY*)(keyBlob + sizeof(BLOBHEADER));`  
 From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838123/error-importing-public-key-using-cryptoapi-cryptimportkey

Comment: Shouldn't it be `blobheader.aiKeyAlg = CALG_RSA_SIGN` instead of `CALG_RSA_KEYX` , since he want to use it with `CryptVerifySignature()` ?

Comment: @CITBL A key imported with CALG_RSA_SIGN can only be used for verification, while a key imported with CALG_RSA_KEYX can be used for both encryption and verification. CALG_RSA_SIGN would work too, but CALG_RSA_KEYX is not _wrong_. It also means that the code can be used for multiple purposes, and since this is the public key there should be no security implications.